# Is it possible to estimate the execution time of an FPGA design?

Tags: fpga, clock, latch, vivado, timing-analysis

Is it possible to evaluate the "execution" time of an FPGA design?

I think that if you have a design where you only have And, Or, Not, etc. gates, the result only depends on the inputs.

But now with FF-latches there is a timing constraint, isn't it? I mean, for example if you have the following design :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwVYOl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the input changes, it will takes 3 clock cycles for the output to be updated ?

Knowing that, I have a more complex design in Vivado where I can't count the FF-latches in order to determine the "longest" path. But is there an option or a way to do it ?

Bonus question : does a look-up table operation take one clock cycle to be completed ?

Comment: no, if you only have combinatorial gates, these still have setup and propagation times: nothing in this world is instantaneous. And in FPGA practice, the time a FF takes to latch a value is typically orders of magnitude *smaller* than the things you do combinatorially in between flip flops, so you've got everything the wrong way around

Comment: Oh ok so I was wrong all along... Thank you for enlightening me on that topic by the way ! Actually that does not really change my original question that was to know if it is possible to find the longest path in order to determine the "delay" that there is between the input and the output !

Comment: well, yes, any FPGA synthesis tool does that.

Comment: Ok thank you very much ! I will look for futher information in Vivado documentation.

Comment: have you got a simulator?

Comment: I'm using the simulator integrated to Vivado, I don't know it's name...

Comment: When you have a design and finally built it for a specific FPGA, you'll get a report that says "max frequency: …" and that will, pretty much, be the inverse of the propagation delay through the longest combinatorial chain in your design.

Comment: As I understand, you don't need to estimate the *propagation delay* (which applies only to combinatorial, and is well calculated by the development tools), but you need to check the *latency* (number of clock cycles required to process your stuff) of your system. The tools can't help you on that. Only you can tell, depending on what you system does and the way it does it. If you can't tell it, it means you don't understand your own design. A FPGA design is a state machine. If you don't know exactly through which states your machine goes, you have a problem that can't be solved by any tool.

Comment: (oh, and I forgot to mention: FPGAs don't contain AND, OR or NOT gates, they usually consist of small look up tables that they use to "emulate these".)

Comment: Actually i know how to find that maximum frequency, but what I wanted to know is if it was possible to determine the latency (thanks dim for the exact term). My design is composed of processes, and I know what path my input takes through those processes. What I don't know is if a process runs in one clock cycles or more.

Comment: Again, this most certainly isn't possible. How come you don't know how many cycles you need to get your output? You didn't do the design yourself, did you?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not very clear, I'll try to be as clear as I can. Let's say my main design is composed of three processes. An input goes through process A, then B, then C. The steps within a process are sequential, aren't they? How then can I estimate the latency in a process? Does any step in my process (such as assigning my output) last for one clock cycle or less?

Comment: @Cedric No the process does NOT have STEPS in the sense that a software type thinks of them, at best the order of the lines in a process expresses priority (Last assignment wins), not sequence. An if statement in a process infers a mux, a edge triggered if (rising_edge...) a register, and assignments are just how you wire things up. These are hardware, they have propagation delay but no sequence, if you want sequence you have to build a state machine or at least register things with a clock. Now the simulator does things very slightly differently, read up on delta cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run a functional simulation to determine signal latency. A complex design can have many paths from inputs to outputs and there is no way for the timing analysis tools to know which particular path is of interest to you. Write a testbench, wiggle the inputs, and count the clock cycles until the outputs change.

Whether a LUT operation takes one clock cycle depends on the delay through the LUT and your chosen clock frequency. That sounds like a silly answer, but the question is poorly framed. An FPGA cannot do anything interesting if you run the clock so fast that a signal can't propagate through a single LUT, so every useful FPGA design has a clock period that is (much) longer than the delay through a single LUT.

Comment: Thank you for the advice ! Actually I checked my testbench and something was missing ! Now I can observe really well the latency of my design. Thank you also for the second part of the answer.